# How to edit a portion of a xml file using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a xml file.

in the file there are some file name like a.txt,b.txt.

Now everytime it will be changed and the final filename will be like this:

file name =a_Currentdate_V1.txt

same goes for B.txt

How can I do this using SSIS? what should i write in the script file?

Comment: can u give some more info?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with a script task.

Comment: Like in the xml

<Table Name="AA"> <Files> <File FileName="AAA.txt"/> </Files>

I want somthing

<Table Name="AA"> <Files> <File FileName="AAA_201411_V1.txt"/> </Files>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using script task, pass the directory path to foreach container to iterate over file, write script task in foreach container which will read all data from xml/text file, modify it and then write the modified data to the file again, refer below code.

```
string data=System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path/to/the/file");

  //data= Manipulate data here
  //.......
  //.......

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path/to/the/file",data);
```

that's it and you can now move or copy file anywhere you want using File System Task